# How would I Group by a column in Pandas, and find its sum?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset, df1

```
 Length  Duration
  90     10
  90     3
  90     5
  80     2
  80     2
```

I need to groupby Length and then sum

I am thinking I will have to

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.groupby['Length'].count ???
```

Desired Output:

```
Length    Sum

90         18      
80         4
```

dput

```
structure(list(Duration = c(10L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L), Length = c(90L, 
90L, 90L, 80L, 80L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sum` method in pandas

```
df.groupby('Length')['Duration'].sum()
```

Let me know if this helps!!